# Iteratively find N nodes with highest attribute values

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a directed, weighted graph `G` in Networkx. Each node has a `'value'` attribute. I am trying to write a code that does the following:

1. Starting from a source node `i`, find all incoming (outgoing) nodes
2. Select `N` nodes with the highest `'value'` attribute
3. Repeat step 1 for all incoming (outgoing) nodes of `i`, iteratively for `K` loops

Ultimately, I would like to have a list of the nodes visited. I would like to allow for nodes to be revisited in this procedure.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: To find the N most valuable nodes: Iterate over the nodes in the graph, keeping track of the N most valuable nodes as you go along.  To find the nodes reachable from the source, run the Dijkstra algorithm.  To find the N most valuable reachable nodes, run Dijkstra to find reachable nodes, then iterate over them to find the most valuable.